# Append the first half of the first line of /etc/hosts to a conf file

Tags: bash, linux

I have to edit a config automatically before starting a service in a docker container (a storm supervisor), and I want to append something like this in `/opt/storm/conf/storm.yaml`: `storm.local.hostname: 1.1.1.1` (extracted from `/etc/hosts`)

What I currently do is that:

```
echo -n "storm.local.hostname: " >> /opt/storm/conf/storm.yaml && head -1 /etc/hosts | awk -F ' ' {'print $1'} | xargs echo >> /opt/storm/conf/storm.yaml
```

How can I improve on that, on a readability POV? It looks pretty obfuscated to me, but I may just be naive ^^

Disclaimer: this runs inside a docker container, so there's only access to classic bash.

Comment: What is special about the line of `/etc/hosts` that makes it the correct entry to fetch? Why aren't you looking up a hostname instead?

Comment: @200_success : In my docker container, "hostname" returns the container tag (so something like adef456fd), and I'm interested in the ip of the container (so something like 1.1.1.1), and I found out there's the resolution in /etc/hosts If there's a better solution, I totally can hear it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I improve on that, on a readability POV? It looks pretty obfuscated to me, but I may just be naive ^^

You're not naive, it looks obfuscated ;-)

A couple of general tips first:

- When you find yourself writing the same path twice, put it in a variable

  - to avoid duplicated hard coded strings
  - to make it easy to change the path later if needed
  - to give it a meaningful descriptive name
- Avoid `echo -n`. In general, avoid all `echo` statements that use any flags like `-n`, `-e`, because these are not portable. When you need those extra functions, `printf` is more portable. Plain `echo` with no flags, just stuff to print is nice, short and sweet
- When you see `head` and `awk` in the same pipeline, usually you can rewrite with just `awk`. It saves the execution of one process.
- I think `head -NUM` is deprecated. To be safe, I suggest to use `head -n NUM` instead.
- To avoid extremely long lines, break the line with a `\`

A couple of specific tips in the context of your example:

- The one-liner first appends some fixed text to the config file,
  and then appends some more text by way of `awk`.
  Since `awk` can print fixed text too, the `echo` is not needed at all.
- `xargs` seems pointless: you could just redirect the output of `awk`
- The separator `' '` you used with `awk` seems both unnecessary and error prone. The hosts file might have entries separated by tab. Simply by not specifying a separator, `awk` will work with both cases, space or tab separated.

Following the suggestions above, the one-liner could be simplified to:

```
awk '{print "storm.local.hostname: " $1; exit}' < /etc/hosts >> /opt/storm/conf/storm.yaml
```

Comment: This looks good, and works flawlessly. Thanks :)

Comment: The ` < ` is not required I believe?

Comment: On my system, it doesn't appear to do a difference indeed :)